# MySQL User-Defined Variable Values Can't be Used as Identifiers. How do I do this?

Tags: mysql, variables

According to the manual:

> User variables... cannot be used
>   directly in an SQL statement as an
>   identifier or as part of an
>   identifier, such as in contexts where
>   a table or database name is expected

Which explains why what I've been trying doesn't work:

```
set @databaseName := 'job_hunt_2';

drop database @databaseName;
create database @databaseName;
use @databaseName;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this, or is it simply impossible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be you should try following approach:

```
set @databaseName := 'job_hunt_2';
SET @s = CONCAT('drop database ', @databaseName); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```